# php/ajax fileupload process?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, process, workflow

I am wondering what the best workflow would be to handle this process.

Basic steps are.

The user selects a csv file and uploads it.
The csv file is then checked against a set of rules.

If the csv file is invalid
The user is shown the rows that are invalid.
The user is given the choice to terminate the upload or, strip the invalid lines.

If the csv file is valid, or strip is clicked
The user is shown a screen to choose the filename.

If the filename is already taken the user is given the choice to
a) rename the file (to a name of their choosing)
b) replace existing file.
c) rename the file to filename_1 etc

When the name is chosen a table is created in the database called (csv_filename);
Then data from the csv is entered into the table.
The file is deleted.
The user is taken to a page showing the file data (from the table)

---

My issue is,
This is all run through ajax.
How do I handle reporting what file we are dealing with?

I dont want to pass back the filename in an ajax response as that is too easy to tamper with.

I dont want to create a table to hold the filepath and pass back an id, as it seems to be a waste to have a table for just this.

Comment: One thing to remember: If you have to prompt for what to do in a filename collision, you'll have to save the file on the server somewhere, as PHP will delete it when the request finishes - otherwise the user would have to re-upload the file after each prompt.

Comment: when I upload the file, I save the file in a directory that gets all files older than 30 minutes removed automagically. The part I am stuck on is, how do I make sure I can reference the file at the next prompt, what is the best way to manage this, pass back the whole filename, create a table that has a id/filename link, any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with this, when the file is uploaded in the first step.  Its done, its got a file name, and it can't be terminated because its already there.  It has to be, or how will you analyze it?

From the users perspective you can make it look like thats how its working, which maybe is what you meant.

Anyways, to report what file you're dealing with, store it in a session variable.

Comment: how easily can sessions be tampered with (the data contained in the files is quite sensitive, hence my over the top protection).

also,

by terminate the upload I actually meant terminate the process, hence, A script is run which deletes the file, then they are redirected.

Comment: With regards to entering the filename, I meant A display filename.

data_export_users_19.25.2010.csv is not particularly nice to look at in a list of "files".

Comment: If its shared hosting and you're using the default session handler, its somewhat trivial for anyone on the server to read the data stored in the session, as its just in the /tmp folder as a flat file usually.  And on the client end, there is always the possibility of session hijacking through mitm attack, or some other interception.  Otherwise its fairly safe.

Comment: also, are you meaning store the filename, or a hash thereof?

Comment: Well you'd have to store the filename, a hash is one way, and you wouldn't be able to use it again to refer to the file.  You could encrypt the filename before you put it in the session, but that may be just as much trouble as using a database table for it.